# How to test a function with jasmine?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic2

I have a class with a contructor and some classes:

```
import {Weight} from './weight';
export class Weight {
    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, private user: User, private zone: NgZone, private alert: AlertPopupServices){
    }
    getSomeValue(a,b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test it with jasmine.

```
describe('BLABLABLA', () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

        declarations: [MyApp, Weight],

        providers: [
            SecureStorageServices, NavController, User, AlertPopupServices,
            {provide: ViewController, useClass: ViewControllerMock},
        ],

        imports: [
            IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp), TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                    deps: [Http]
                }
            })
        ]

    }).compileComponents();
    it('has to give the addition of two numbers', () => {
        expect("FUNCTION CALL").toEqual(10);
    });
});
```

But how can I call the function in my it and get the return value?

Thanks

Comment: did you import the class Weight in your tests?

Comment: yes , I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Weight } from './weight';
describe('BLABLABLA', () => {
    let comp:    Weight;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ BannerComponent ], // declare the test component
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Weight);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance; // Weight test instance
    });  

    it('has to give the addition of two numbers', () => {
        expect(comp.getSomeValue(5,5)).toEqual(10);
    });
});
```

Keep your configuration as is, you need to look at the following two links if you are new to testing in angular:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that the class has an injectable:

```
import {Weight} from './weight';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class Weight {
    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, private user: User, private zone: NgZone, private alert: AlertPopupServices){
    }
    getSomeValue(a,b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Put the class in the providers of the testBed

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({

        declarations: [MyApp, Weight],

        providers: [
            SecureStorageServices, NavController, User, AlertPopupServices,
            {provide: ViewController, useClass: ViewControllerMock},
             Weight
        ],

        imports: [
            IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp), TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                    deps: [Http]
                }
            })
        ]

    }).compileComponents();
```

Add an inject to the it section:

```
it('has to give the addition of two numbers', inject([Weight], (weight) => { 
    // call functions using weight variable
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
it('has to give the addition of two numbers', async(inject([Weight], (weight: Weight) => {
      expect(weight.getSomeValue(2,3)).toEqual(5);
})));
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual formula for unit testing is Arrange, Act, Assert. SO in this case:

```
//Arrange
var systemUnderTest: Weight = new Weight(mockViewController, mockNavController, mockUser, etc)

//Act
var result = systemUnderTest.getSomeValue(1,2);

//Assert
expect(result).toEqual(10);
```

When you instantiate your System Under Test (sut), you want to isolate all of its dependencies so that you are only expending your efforts testing the logic in your component and not someone elses. Its all part of SOLID design principals. The dependencies can be mocked, stubbed, ignored. It is beyond the scope of this post to go into all the different ways dependencies can be provided but I hope this gives you a start.